# Why is iTerm2 printing Pytest results in color?

Tags: bash, shell, pytest, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I was playing around with Pytest `--color=yes` option and realized that my Terminal is printing results in color even without it being set.
Why is that?

My terminal setup is this:

- OS: MacOS
- iTerm2 build 3.4.15
- iTerm2 Report terminal type property set to: xterm-256color
- default shell is zsh (oh-my-zsh)
- not sure if anything else matters...

My guess is it has something to do with oh-my-zsh, but I am not sure what, where and how.

I got to this question because I was trying to create SublimeText build system that will print results in colors, without success (not counting using SublimeANSI plugin which works with some quirks).

So, to reiterate the question: I am confused why my terminal app is printing Pytest results in color, even when no `--color=yes` is not set for Pytest.

Comment: If you pipe your command into `cat`, the output will not be in colour, because pytest detects that the output is not a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the [Pytest terminal source](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/c9cf2d44245c553258e7e0ed0e446072b3434d1b/src/_pytest/terminal.py#L204), we'll see the following on the `color` option:

```py
group._addoption(
    "--color",
    metavar="color",
    action="store",
    dest="color",
    default="auto",
    choices=["yes", "no", "auto"],
    help="color terminal output (yes/no/auto).",
)
```

So the default is set to `auto`.

---

Your zsh/oh-my-zsh allows to use the colors and therefore there shown without passing the option yourself.

Comment: Understood. Nice and clear answer, thanks.